# Calculate the future value for only one category using the IRR (Python)

Tags: python, excel, if-statement, for-loop, irr

```
import xlrd
import numpy

fileWorkspace = 'C://Users/jod/Desktop/'

wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(fileWorkspace + 'assign2.xls')
sh1 = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)

time,amount,category = [],[],[]            
for a in range(2,sh1.nrows):
    time.append(int(sh1.cell(a,0).value))        # Pulling time from excel (column A)
    amount.append(float(sh1.cell(a,1).value))    # Pulling amount from excel (column B)
    category.append(str(sh1.cell(a,2).value))    # Pulling category from excel (column C)
#print(time)
#print(amount)
#print(category)
print('\n')

p_p2 = str(sh1.cell(0,1))
p_p1 = p_p2.replace("text:'","")
pp = p_p1.replace("'","")
print(pp)                            # Printing the type of pay period (Row 1, col B)
c_p2 = str(sh1.cell(1,1))
c_p1 = c_p2.replace("text:'","")
cp = c_p1.replace("'","")
print(cp)                            # Printing the type of compound period (Row 2, col B)

netflow = 0
outflow = 0
inflow = 0
flow = 0

cat = ["Sales", "Salvage", "Subsidy", "Redeemable", "Utility", "Labor", 
       "Testing", "Marketing", "Materials", "Logistics"]

if pp == "Years" and cp == "Years":   # if pay period and compound period are both in years

    IRR = numpy.irr(amount) * 100            # Calculates the internal rate of return (IRR)
    print ("IRR:", round(IRR, 2), '%', '\n') # prints (IRR)

    for i in time:              # for every value in time array
        if cat[5] in category:  # if "Labor" for cat array is in category array or not

            # calculates the present values using all the amount values (col B) instead of 
            # just using the ones that has "Labor" category label beside them
            # Need to make every other value 0, such as beside "Redeemable" and "Salvage"
            flow = amount[i] / numpy.power((1 + (IRR/100)), time[i])
            if flow>0:                      
                inflow = inflow + flow      
            if flow<0:                      
                outflow = outflow + flow  

            print ('Present Value (P) is:', round(flow,0), '\n')

    netflow = outflow + inflow
    print("In year 0 or current year")
    print("-------")
    print ('Outflow is: ', round(outflow,0))
    print ('Inflow is: ', round(inflow,0))
    print ('Netflow is: ', round(netflow,0), '\n')

    outflow2 = (round(outflow,0))*(1+(IRR/100))**(9)
    inflow2 = (round(inflow,0))*(1+(IRR/100))**(9)
    netflow2 = outflow2 + inflow2

    print("In year 9")
    print("-------")
    print ('Outflow is: ', round(outflow2,0))
    print ('Inflow is: ', round(inflow2,0))
    print ('Netflow is: ', round(netflow2,0), '\n')
```

I have commented important lines of code for clarification.
Here is the original question:

illustrate the breakdown of major project revenues and expenses by category as a percentage of that project’s future value in year 9. The illustration must also clearly indicate the total future value of the project in year 9 as well as the IRR.

There will be a total of 10 revenue and cost categories that a project may be composed of.  The categories are: Sales, salvage, subsidy, redeemable, utility, labor, testing, marketing, materials and logistics.  All revenues and expenses will fall in one of these ten categories.  The project pay period and compound period will be identified at the top of the Excel sheet.  Pay period and compound period may be designated as any of the following: years, quarters, months.

---

I am getting confused because I am not able to pull the only values from beside the "Labor", "Redeemable", or "Salvage". I just don't know where I am making a mistake, or there is something that is incomplete. Below is the excel file image:

[Excel File Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7DJ6.png)
[Excel File Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7pIx.png)

Answer (score 0):

After revising, all cashflows are discounted at the irr. What is done is the following:
i) determineAdjustments takes the pay period (column A) and adjusts if for the year ended (if it is a monthly amount it puts it in the proper year ended) and if its monthly puts in in the month ended (no adjustment necessary). This will divide the pay period by 12 if yearly cash flows are needed (yearly compounding)

ii) IRR is calculated, and the compounding period is used to adjust the monthly IRR for monthly pay periods

iii) all expenses are discounted at the IRR and input into a list for cat_contributions['category_name'] = [discounted period 1, discounted period 2 ... ]

iv) Then the net inflows and outflows are sums of these.

I can't type up data in the spreadsheets from the images as that would take a while, but maybe tinker with this and see if you can get it to work.

```
from __future__ import division
import xlrd
import numpy
import os
import math

def main(xls = 'xls_name.xlsx', sh = 0):
    #save script in same folder as the xls file
    os.chdir(  os.getcwd() )
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(xls)
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    pay_period = sh.cell_value(0,1)
    compounding_period = sh.cell_value(1,1)

    compounding_factor, pay_factor = determineAdjustments(
        pay_period, compounding_period)

    number_of_periods = max( sh.col_values(0, start_rowx = 2) )

    flow_per_period = [ 0*i for i in range( int( math.ceil( number_of_periods/pay_factor ) ) + 1 ) ]#list of length number of pay_periods
    for r in range(2,sh.nrows):
        pay_period = int( math.ceil( sh.cell_value(r,0) / pay_factor ) )
        flow_per_period[pay_period] += sh.cell_value(r,1) #unadjusted cash flows


    irr = calculateIRR(flow_per_period, compounding_factor)

    cat_contributions = sortExpenditures(sh, irr, pay_factor)
    total_cat_contributions, netflow, total_outflow, total_inflow = calculateFlows(cat_contributions)
    printStats(cat_contributions, irr, compounding_factor, pay_factor,
               total_cat_contributions, netflow, total_outflow, total_inflow)
    return

def determineAdjustments(pay_period, compounding_period):

    if compounding_period == 'years':
        compounding_factor = 1
        if pay_period == 'months':
            pay_factor = 12
        if pay_period == 'years':
            pay_factor = 1
        #assume no days pay periods

    if compounding_period == 'months':
        compounding_factor = 12
        #assume no yearly payouts and that the
        #all payments are in months
        pay_factor = 1


    return compounding_factor, pay_factor

def calculateIRR(cashflow, compounding_factor):

    irr = numpy.irr(cashflow)

    irr_comp = (1 + irr)**compounding_factor - 1

    #seems like in first example it uses rounded irr, can do something like:
    #irr_comp = round(irr_comp,4)
    return irr_comp

def sortExpenditures(sh, irr, pay_factor):
    #percentages and discounting occurs at the IRR caculated in the main
    #function

    cat = ["Sales", "Salvage", "Subsidy", "Redeemable", "Utility", "Labor", 
       "Testing", "Marketing", "Materials", "Logistics"]

    #python dictionary to sort contributions into categories
    cat_contributions = {}
    for c in cat:
        cat_contributions[c] = []

    # create list of contributions of each list item to FV in a dictionary
    for r in range(2,sh.nrows):
        try:
            #discounted cash flow of each expenditure
            #using formula FV = expenditure/(1+i)^n
            cat_contributions[sh.cell_value(r,2)].append(
                sh.cell_value(r,1) / ( (1 + irr) ** (sh.cell_value(r,0)/pay_factor) )
                )

        except KeyError:
            print "No category for type: " + sh.cell_value(r,2) +'\n'

    return cat_contributions

def calculateFlows(cat_contributions):

    total_outflow = 0
    total_inflow = 0

    total_cat_contributions = {}

    for cat in cat_contributions:
        total_cat_contributions[cat] = sum( cat_contributions[cat] )
        if total_cat_contributions[cat] < 0:
            total_outflow += total_cat_contributions[cat]
        else:
            total_inflow += total_cat_contributions[cat]

    netflow = total_inflow + total_outflow

    return total_cat_contributions, netflow, total_outflow, total_inflow

def printStats(cat_contributions, irr, compounding_factor, pay_period,
               total_cat_contributions, netflow, total_outflow, total_inflow):

    print "IRR: "+str(irr*100) +'  %'
    if compounding_factor == 1: print "Compounding: Yearly"
    if compounding_factor == 12: print "Compounding: Monthly"

    if pay_period == 1: "Cashflows: Year Ended"
    if pay_period == 12: "Cashflows: Month Ended"

    print "Future Value (Net Adjusted Cashflow): " +str(netflow) 
    print "Adjusted Inflows: " + str(total_inflow)
    print "Adjusted Outflows: " + str(total_outflow) +'\n'


    for cat in total_cat_contributions:
        if total_cat_contributions[cat] != 0:
            print '-----------------------------------------------------'
            print cat + '\n'
            print "Total Contribution to FV " + str( total_cat_contributions[cat] )
            if total_cat_contributions[cat] < 0:
                print "Contribution to Expenses: " + str ( abs(100 * total_cat_contributions[cat]/total_outflow) )
            else:
                print "Contribution to Revenues: " + str ( abs(100 * total_cat_contributions[cat]/total_inflow) ) +'\n'


main(xls='Book1.xlsx')
```

Comment: line 41 error: `flow_per_year[int( sh1.cell_value(r,0) )] += sh1.cell_value(r,1) #unadjusted cash flows` `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Sorry, I think I assumed that that was all the rows in the sheet from the image provided. I have changed all the sh1.nrows to the value '13'. Try and see if that works?

Comment: It does give me results. However, it is printing everything once at once and then printing everything again. Also, I am very confused on what your codes is all about. Let me see what exactly you are doing and I will get back to you.

Comment: There are few errors in the code, which is producing incorrect results. The IRR you have calculated is correct. However, the inflows - outflows is not because the answer is suppose to $1.65, and you have $2036.53. Also, how to deal in a condition where the pay period and compound period are different. There are nine possibilities of combination. It gets much more complicated when pp and cp are different. In fact, the IRR module that we have to calculate won't be useful I believe.  I have worked so hard on this. I truly appreciate your help. I am really hoping that you will help me finish it.

Comment: Also, different files would have different categories in any order with any number of years. I mean this code needs to able to pull and do calculations from any excel file there is given in any pp and cp condition. Need a general code.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you will be able to help or not? so I can find another way.

Comment: Sorry jod, I can help more if you like. It is difficult to say without more examples. First, can you post maybe your entire excel sheet with multiple examples? I only have the one screen shot to work off. From there I can see about a few functions for the IRR and future value with different compounding periods. Also, the 2036.53 is dependent on your discount rate. A discount rate (variable called interest_rate) affects this.

Comment: The discount rate = IRR gives you a future value of 0, keep in mind. So, if you set the discount rate = 0.0629 (the approximate IRR) you get the future vale of $1.64. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I added the other images I have. Now for "Excel File Image 2", the IRR is 298.88% and netflow is $0.00 at PW. For Image 3, the IRR is 2.08% and netflow is $2.40 at PW. I had to delete the first Image because I can only post two links. If you could just get me a working code that takes pp and cp into consideration the way I want it, and everything else mentioned in the question, then that would be awesome. Also could you email me the code at joddoj3@gmail.com because it is really hard to paste it from here.

Comment: See above, you will have to tinker with it a bit, but this should be a good starting point to get a generalized program working.

Comment: I am getting the directory not found error. Where do I need to have all my files? I need them to be on desktop. Also, did u take quarters into consideration as well because I don't see it in the code. Along with that, as I said there would be 9 different possible scenarios. So, pp = quarters cp = months, pp = years cp=months, pp=months cp=quarters, and so on. I would appreciate if you could add that on there.

Comment: I got the directory problem fixed. I wasn't reading your comment. Another error though. `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'compounding_factor' referenced before assignment`

Comment: I can't do anything with your code unless it works. I need to see some output.

Comment: You need to then have the code above in say irr.py on your desktop with your excel files. Then you run it by typing " main(xls = 'xls_sheet_name.xlsx') " at the bottom - remove main(xls = 'Book1.xlsx'). Test on the first image you sent me, that should be a good starting point for you, I think you have a good start on working through the rest of the problem by trouble shooting. Check the if statements in the determineAdjustments function for how to add quarters etc.

Comment: I got so few errors fixed, but there are still many other errors in the code, which I can't fix. Also, it is completely different than my original code, so it is hard to understand it as well. Still no output only errors.